# I want to clear browsing history before open the browser

Tags: python, selenium

I have put code on selenium, where browser get refreshed after 20 second. However I want to put some more code on it, that before opening the browser it will clear history, cache and after whole work, it will get close close and again open and clear history, cache and cookies here is my code :

```
import time from selenium 
import webdriver as wd 
chromedriver - r"D:\bot\chromedriver.exe" 
driver=wd.chrome(executable_path=chromedriver) 
driver.get("http:\youtu.be/RsWCo_xGXxY") 
refresh_rate = 20 
while True: 
    time.sleep(refresh_rate) 
    driver.refresh()
```

Comment: you can use driver.delete_all_cookies()

Comment: create a new instance of webdriver... it will start the browser with a new/blank profile.

Comment: Could you please provide me the code.

Answer (score 1):

To clear all browser history you can use this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_path = r"D:\bot\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path) # creates new webdriver instance

driver.get("http:\youtu.be/RsWCo_xGXxY")
driver.delete_all_cookies() # deletes all coockies
refresh_rate = 20
while True:
    time.sleep(refresh_rate)
    driver.refresh()
```

Output:

[image: img]